# SQL Multiple Rows to Multiple Columns for reporting (unknown number of needed columns)

Tags: sql, denormalization

I have searched many of the denormalization and multiple Rows to Multiple Column posts and none seem to do what i want.

I have  a table with duplicate ID with different values in other fields an ID can have anywhere from 1-20 rows depending on how many associated records there are.

Example:

```
Input - 
ID  Name    Address
1   A         A1
1   B         A2
1   C         A3
1   C         A4

Output - 
ID  Name1   Address1    Name2   Address2    Name3   Address3    Name4   Address4
1   A         A1          B       A2          C       A3          C        A4
```

I wrote some really ugly SQL that checks the each field before inserting but i am hoping there is a cleaner way as this is very inflexible to changes. Any thoughts!

```
 COL_1 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_1 END),
COL_2 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_2 END),
COL_3 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_3 END),
COL_4 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_4 END),
COL_5 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_5 END),
COL_6 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_6 END),
COL_7 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_7 END),
COL_8 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_8 END),
COL_9 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_9 END),
COL_10 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_10 END),
COL_11 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_11 END),
COL_12 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_12 END),
COL_13 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_13 END),
COL_14 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_14 END),
COL_15 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NOT NULL and COL_15 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_15 END),
COL_16 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NOT NULL and COL_15 IS NOT NULL and COL_16 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_16 END),
COL_17 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NOT NULL and COL_15 IS NOT NULL and COL_16 IS NOT NULL and COL_17 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_17 END),
COL_18 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NOT NULL and COL_15 IS NOT NULL and COL_16 IS NOT NULL and COL_17 IS NOT NULL and COL_18 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_18 END),
COL_19 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NOT NULL and COL_15 IS NOT NULL and COL_16 IS NOT NULL and COL_17 IS NOT NULL and COL_18 IS NOT NULL and COL_19 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_19 END),
COL_20 = (CASE WHEN COL_1 IS NOT NULL and COL_2 IS NOT NULL and COL_3 IS NOT NULL and COL_4 IS NOT NULL and COL_5 IS NOT NULL and COL_6 IS NOT NULL and COL_7 IS NOT NULL and COL_8 IS NOT NULL and COL_9 IS NOT NULL and COL_10 IS NOT NULL and COL_11 IS NOT NULL and COL_12 IS NOT NULL and COL_13 IS NOT NULL and COL_14 IS NOT NULL and COL_15 IS NOT NULL and COL_16 IS NOT NULL and COL_17 IS NOT NULL and COL_18 IS NOT NULL and COL_19 IS NOT NULL and COL_20 IS NULL THEN @CLINE ELSE COL_20 END),
```

Thanks,
Matt

Updated to show final output:
[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvuZ6.png)

Comment: How are you using the results once you get them back? Have you thought about returning groups of all the data with the same ID? (i.e. the GROUP BY function)

Comment: Perhaps a cursor would be the way to go? I could be completely off the mark there, but it *sounds* like that sort of problem.

Comment: Joe - I am actually using a cursor to populate the variables then i need to take those viable to see if the 1st set of columns is filled or not.  If it is move on to the 2nd set of columns.

Comment: Taraz - I am creating a table with one row based on ID's then using this data in a report. So each set of columns will result on a line in the report. Its kind of like i have to denormalize the table to to normalize it the report report. I added the output example above!